# SOAP Request: How to make multiple request messages in sequence

Tags: soap, request, soapui

I have a SOAP endpoint and will be having more than 1000 request messages which have different values for the request parameters but same operation of SOAP Message. I want to execute them in a sequence if the previous request that got triggered was 200 OK?

Is there any way to do this without JAVA program? Is there any client that will help me?

Comment: You can use soapui and then put a simple groovy script to stop if status from a request is not 200. Otherwise it will pick the values from a property file one by one and proceed executing the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already have some sort of loop in your test case that reads your variable properties from a file or perhaps Excel and feeds them into your SOAP request. Ready API/soapUI Pro gives you this functionality, but for open source soapUI you'll have to write your own Groovy test steps.

Then, you can use a soapUI Compliance, Status and Standards assertion to check you've received a valid or invalid HTTP status code and react accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I accepted your answer as I did try to use SOAP UI but I also found a separate workaround using Curl and Batch script.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to do this without JAVA program? Is there any client
>   that will help me?

After re-reading the question, it seems to me you're not yet using SoapUI, though it has been tagged as a SoapUI question.  It happens quite a lot on here where people are askign general SOAP questions, but tag SoapUI.  BTW, Craig's answer should be accepted if you are using SoapUI.

In terms of options, you have lots....

- Code.  You can use Python, C#, Java, Javascript, etc. etc. to create a program that will call your endpoint.  Any programming language will have the libraries to call web services.  So, if you do know a language, you could use that.
- SoapUI.  There is a free version, which will allow you to call web services.  In your question, you want to call the same service over and over with different parameters.  In testing speak, this is a data-driven test.  These can be achieved in the free SoapUI, but it is a fiddle.  However, the full-licensed version offers data-driven tests out of the box.  I use these all the time.  Very easy to set-up.  If you use SoapUI, then Craig's answer about using Assertions would stop the test if you got a status code other than a 200.
- Postman.  this is another free tool, which I have used a little.  I haven't tried data-driven tests, but I'm sure the docs will tell you if they're supported.  If you try Postman, then you ought to look at Danny Dainton's excellent tutorial on [GitHub](https://github.com/DannyDainton/All-Things-Postman)
- JMeter.  Another free tool.  This is primarily used for performance and load testing, but would still meet your needs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed answer. I managed to do the required by using Curl and batch script.